# Error while splitting pcollections on Dataflow runner

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have an Apache Beam pipeline built in python. I am reading rows from a csv file.Then there are generic pipeline steps for All pcollections. This works fine. For pcollections which come from a specific filename, I want to perform couple of additional steps. 
Therefore I tag the pcollections in that file and run additional steps for those tagged collections.
Wehn I run the pipeline on 'Dataflow' it gives me the error "Workflow failed. Causes: Expected custom source to have non-zero number of splits. "

I tested and this works fine on 'DirectRunner'.

```
lines = (p | beam.io.ReadFromText(input_file_path, skip_header_lines=1))

Generic = (lines | <"Do generic logic for all pCollections">)

tagged_lines = (lines | beam.ParDo(Tag(),input_file_path).with_outputs(Tag.TAG_OPTOUT,Tag.TAG_BOUNCE))

Optouts = (tagged_lines[Tag.TAG_OPTOUT] | <"Do logic 1">)

Bounces = (tagged_lines[Tag.TAG_BOUNCE] | <"Do logic 2">)
```

```
class Tag(beam.DoFn):
    TAG_OPTOUT = 'OPTOUT'
    TAG_BOUNCE = 'BOUNCE'
    def process(self, element,input_file_path):
        input_file = input_file_path.get()
        if "optout" in input_file:
            yield pvalue.TaggedOutput(self.TAG_OPTOUT, element)
        elif "bounce" in input_file:
        yield pvalue.TaggedOutput(self.TAG_BOUNCE, element)
```

Comment: The DataflowRunner attempts to split sources (files in your case) so that the files can be processed in parallel while the DirectRunner doesn't. So this is likely a bug within the implementation of TextSource and it would be useful to narrow down what criteria is triggering it. Do you have any files that are empty or only have the header line in them in your failed run? Do you know what is a minimal case that would reproduce the error?

Comment: Thanks Lukasz for your reply. Currently I'm testing a single file with 3 rows. The Filename has the word 'bounce', so I want all the rows in it to be tagged as TAG_BOUNCE. Does it fail because All records in the file were categorized into single category?

Comment: That shouldn't be the issue. Also, since your using a single file with 3 rows, we know that it isn't empty. Does the input_file_path point to a file that exists on GCS?

Comment: Yes it does. I also tried hard coding the path to GCS location in the Tag() pardo function. The other thing I tried is to remove everything in the Tag() function and just default the value to TAG_BOUNCE.

Comment: Which version of Apache Beam are you using?

Comment: I'm also getting the same error when I'm using ReadFromText to read a non-empty file. Have you found the issue?

Comment: Please have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56868887/beam-dataflow-custom-python-job-cloud-storage-to-pubsub