# Beam / Dataflow Custom Python job - Cloud Storage to PubSub

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

I need to perform a very simple transformation on some data (extract a string from JSON), then write it to PubSub - I'm attempting to use a custom python Dataflow job to do so.

I've written a job which successfully writes back to Cloud Storage, but my attempts at even the simplest possible write to PubSub (no transformation) result in an error: `JOB_MESSAGE_ERROR: Workflow failed. Causes: Expected custom source to have non-zero number of splits.`

Has anyone successfully written to PubSub from GCS via Dataflow?

Can anyone shed some light on what is going wrong here?

```py
def run(argv=None):

  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--input',
                      dest='input',
                      help='Input file to process.')
  parser.add_argument('--output',
                      dest='output',                      
                      help='Output file to write results to.')
  known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

  pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
  pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
  with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

    lines = p | ReadFromText(known_args.input)

    output = lines #Obviously not necessary but this is where my simple extract goes

    output | beam.io.WriteToPubSub(known_args.output) # This doesn't
```

Comment: So it is saying the source has non-zero number of splits meaning it sounds like your source file is empty? If it was the write to pub sub failing I would expect it to say sink vs source.

Comment: Thanks! So what's confusing me is that a batch job which writes to another GCS bucket, but with everything bar the `Write` method in code, and the `--streaming` flag, works exactly as expected. 

So I now suspect that it's related to this issue I since found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56277145/error-while-splitting-pcollections-on-dataflow-runner, and is potentially that I'm trying to mangle together a bounded read and an unbounded write.

I found a workaround by writing a Scala batch job, but still very curious as to what this is all about!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it isn't possible to achieve this scenario because when you are using streaming mode in Dataflow, [the only source you can use is PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#what_data_sources_and_sinks_are_supported_in_streaming_mode). And you can't switch to batch mode because the apache beam [PubSub sources and sinks](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.13.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.html) are only available for streaming (for remote execution like the Dataflow runner).

That is the reason why you can execute your pipeline without the WriteToPubSub and streaming flag.

Comment: That explains it! Scala Dataflow jobs do support streaming from GCS, and that's what we ultimately ended up doing. Thanks for sharing!